# How to convert numerically indexed array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this

```
{"1":{"name":"cat"},"2":{"name":"elephant"}}
```

how to convert it to

```
[{"name":"dog"},{"name":"cat"}]
```

or convert it to vice versa

Comment: Your goal is still an equivalent to PHP's indexed array, not an associative array. And the code you give us is Json, not PHP, I am not sure what PHP has to do with this? You sure it's not javascript you need?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673259/6374322

Comment: You have provided a JSON, with multilevel in it, Like Multidimensional Array.

Comment: Trying to answer this question without knowing how the JSON array is created, is moot. It is also most likely only going to give the wrong answer.

Comment: actually the scenario is, i have a numeric array. if i delete a value from that array rather than the 1st, 2nd , 3rd --- nth position it creates a numerically indexed array. But, if i delete last value that array it creates associative array. so,, i have to add a conversion method if i delete the last value. because i need numerically indexed array.

Comment: yes.. it is json array.

Comment: check this link... this is my previous problem ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385667/same-json-array-delete-process-produces-different-result-array-for-different-pos/

Comment: How do you delete this value? Show us the PHP code that generates above result, and we can help you. Everything else will just be guesswork, and (bad) workarounds.

Comment: above your comment i have provided a link to my problem.. on that problem i have whole code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = json_decode('{"1":{"name":"cat"},"2":{"name":"elephant"}}');
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $data = ['name' => $item->name];
    $result[] = $data;
}

$json = json_encode($result);
print_r($json);
```